# Postgres Sequence is generating negative values as primary keys

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table which uses a sequence to auto-generate the Primary Key when inserting a record. However, the sequence is generating negative values.

How do I enforce that only positive values are generated and is there a way to generated the ids randomly (especially a varchar type)

## questionnaries.sql #

```
CREATE TABLE public.questionnaries
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('questionnaries_id_seq'::regclass),
  personname character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  question character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  response character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT questionnaries_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.questionnaries
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

## questionnaries_id_seq

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.questionnaries_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 6
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE public.questionnaries_id_seq
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Do the ids need to be random?  Life is easier if you just declare the id column like so: `id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: @BShaps, if there is an option of creating a alpha-numeric random primary key

Comment: There are hacky ways to do the alpha-numeric method.  If just a numeric randomish primary key is okay then you could use `pseudo_encrypt`.  Let me know if you want me to show you the alpha-numeric way in an answer.

Comment: @BShape , please let me know how psuedo_encrypt works, also any idea why the current sequence is generating negative ids?

Comment: My best guess would be something to do with overflow from your integer value.  The max value for an integer is 2,147,483,647, but your sequence goes up to values far higher than that.  Usually Postgres throws an error for that, but maybe for a sequence paired with a primary key column it does something like give a negative number. [pseudo_encrypt wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pseudo_encrypt)

Answer (score 4):

First Create a Sequence like below .Whichever number you wanna start give that for e.g. 0 or 100.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE questionnaries_id_seq START 0;
```

you can query also

```
SELECT nextval('questionnaries_id_seq');
```

Comment: Updating the original post by adding the sequence definition.

Comment: will calling `nextval('questionnaries_id_seq')` on `START 0` return `1` or `0` when called the first time?

Answer (score 4):

The Sequence generate the negative value in two scenarios,

1# you have created the sequence and specify the INCREMENT BY values in a negative("-1").

2# The sequence INCREMENT BY is in positive and correct form but, sequence reached to their MAX value and that's the reason it started generating the MIN value of the sequence.

**There will two solutions for this,**

1. Use the "NO MAXVALUE" with "NO CYCLE" parameter of the sequence as specified below.

   > ```
   > CREATE SEQUENCE <>
   > NO MAXVALUE
   > START WITH 0
   > INCREMENT BY 1
   > NO CYCLE;
   > ```
2. Use the "SERIAL" to generate the numerical values by PostgreSQL.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE table_name (
        column_1 integer PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('serial'),
        column_2 varchar(40) NOT NULL
   );
   ```

Comment: The sequence create is on the similar lines. I have added the sequence definition to the original post. The sequence is auto-generated because I am using SERIAL, still it generates negative primary keys

Comment: How much records you have currently in Database table "questionnaries", and what is the maximum value of ID contains in table "questionnaries".

Comment: at the moment less than 100, as I am developing a proof of concept. However, will expect it to scale later